# Intel 8086, infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to code a little application where a random number between 1-5 is generated using the system clock and the user has to guess the number and a message is displayed if the guess is correct.

Here is my code so far:

```
org 0x100


;Guess:
        MOV AH,2CH  ;DOS CALL TO GET SYSTEM CLOCK
        INT 21H     ;EXECUTE INTERRUPT 21H
        MOV AL,DL   ;RESULT RETURNED IN DL
        MOV AH,0    ;CLEAR THE HIGH BYTE
        MOV CL,20   ;GET DIVISOR
        DIV CL      ;DIVIDE VALUE IN AX BY VALUE IN CL
        MOV BL,AL   ;MOVE RESULT OF DIVISION INTO BL
        INC BL      ;INCREMENT BL TO GET NO BETWEEN 1-5

;Prompt:
        JMP START
        MSG DB "Enter a number between 1-5:$"

        START:  

        MOV DX, OFFSET MSG
        MOV AH, 09h 
        INT 21h

;User input:

        MOV AH, 1h  ;GET INPUT FROM THE KEYBOARD 
        INT 21h     ;THE CHARACTER INPUT IS STORED IN AL

;The Comparison: 

        ;MOV AX,AL   ;LOAD VALUE OF AL (USER INPUT)
        CMP AL,BL   ;COMPARE WITH BL

        JE Equal    ;IF EQUAL JUMP TO Equal
        JNE Not_Equal;IF NOT EQUAL JUMP TO Not_Equal        

        Equal:

        ABC DB "Your guess was correct!$"
        MOV DX, OFFSET ABC
        MOV AH, 09h 
        INT 21h        


        Not_Equal:

        DEF DB "Your guess was incorrect!$"
        MOV DX, OFFSET DEF
        MOV AH, 09h 
        INT 21h
```

My problem is that it just goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: You're looking for a conditional jump. `je`, `jz`, `jg` etc.

Comment: JE Equal    ;IF EQUAL JUMP TO Equal
    JNE Not_Equal;IF NOT EQUAL JUMP TO Not_Equal

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few different problems in your code:

You can't mix code and data like this:

```
    ABC DB "Your guess was correct!$"
    MOV DX, OFFSET ABC
```

The CPU can't tell the difference between code and data and will try to execute whatever it encounters. Move the result strings to the same place where you've got the `MSG` string.

---

You're comparing numeric values with their corresponding ASCII characters:

```
    MOV AH, 1h  ;GET INPUT FROM THE KEYBOARD 
    INT 21h     ;THE CHARACTER INPUT IS STORED IN AL
```

If you enter the digit `2` in the terminal you'd get the character `'2'` (which is equal to 50) in `AL`. To successfully compare that against what you've got in `BL` you have to subtract `'0'` from `AL`.

---

You'll always print the "Your guess was incorrect" string. After the code that prints the "Your guess was correct" string there's no jump to skip the next print:

```
    ABC DB "Your guess was correct!$"
    MOV DX, OFFSET ABC
    MOV AH, 09h 
    INT 21h        

    ; Execution will simply continue here since there's nothing that changes the
    ; flow of execution.

    Not_Equal:
```

---

You're not terminating the program properly. At the end of your program you should add something like:

```
MOV AX,4C00h
INT 21h    ; Terminate with exit code 00h
```